# Relation between complex measure and finite positive measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am struggling on 1 part of the following problem which was part of an assignment in functional analysis.

Problem: Let $(\Omega, B)$ be a measurable space and the $\mu: B\to \mathbb{C}$. be a finitely additive function. Show that $\mu$ us a complex measure iff there exists a finite positive measure m such that for all $A\in B : |\mu(A)| \leq m(A)$.

I have solved the part which assumes the existence of complex measure but I am not able to make any progress on the converse part.

Can you please guide me?

Comment: As I understand you were able to show that if $|\mu(A)|\le m(a)$ then $\mu$ is countably additive and you need the converse, right ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show the countable additivity, that is, $$ \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n)$$
for disjoint $\{A_n\}_n$.

By the assumption that $\mu$ is finitely positive, for every $N$,
$$ \mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N} A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(A_n).$$

By the continuity of finite measures,
$$ \left|\mu\left(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \setminus \cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n\right)\right| \le m\left(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \setminus \cup_{n=1}^{N} A_n\right) \to 0, \ N \to \infty.$$

Furthermore,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\mu(A_n)| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m(A_n) = m\left(\bigcup_{n \ge 1} A_n\right) < +\infty,$$
and hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(A_n) \to \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n), \ N \to \infty.$$

---

The opposite part follows from the Hahn decomposition.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure) Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be the real and imaginary parts of $\mu$. Then they are finite signed measures. Let $|\mu_1|$ and $|\mu_2|$ be the variation measures. Then they are finite measures. Let $m := |\mu_1| + |\mu_2|$.

Comment: Thank you very much for writing the answer. I am struggling to deduce the last line of proof 1 ie : $"\sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(A_n) \to \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_n), \ N \to \infty"$ using the rest of the proof( rest of the proof is clear to me). Kindly explain the deduction done in the last line of the proof.

Comment: This is the definition of the infinite sum.

Comment: But How to deduce it?

Comment: In general, every absolutely convergent infinite series converges. More specifically, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| < +\infty$, then, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ exists. (Let $b_N := \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n$. Then, by the assumption, $(b_N)_N$ is a Cauchy sequence. Now use the completeness of real numbers. )